# Is it possible to add a 'through'model to a child model on Django?

Tags: django, inheritance, model

Here is an condensed example of what I am trying to do:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)

class Individual(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class BookingAgent(Entity)
    staff = models.ManyToManyField(Individual, through='Role', related_name="employee")

class Role(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Individual)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Entity)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=70)
```

Basically, I have a  parent class called `Entity` that stores all of the basic information for a company i.e. address, etc. I then have a `BookingAgent` that is the child of the `Entity`. When I try to create a through relationship on the `BookingAgent` model it doesn't work. I get the error:

> 'staff' is a manually-defined m2m relation through model Role, which does not have foreign keys to Individual and BookingAgent

But it works when the through relationship is defined in the Entity` model.

My goal is to have each Entity have a list of individuals that are employees or members. I think I understand why it is not working but I can't figure out an elegant solution.

Thanks!

UPDATE: To clarify, Entity isn't an abstract base class because there will be some Entities that are not BookingAgents, ManagementCompanies, etc

Comment: *Technically*, there's nothing wrong with what you have. If `BookingAgent` is-a `Entity` then you should be able to save it to any `ForeignKey` that accepts `Entity`. However, with the way Django sets up the M2M API, this won't work. In order for the API to function properly, it must attach related managers to both sides of the relationship, i.e. `Individual` and `BookingAgent` but your code will rather cause related managers to be added to `Individual` and `Entity`. You might call this a bug, but I would imagine the Django devs would mark it WONTFIX if you submitted it.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPratt! I looked up Managers but I am still confused as to how I can solve this. Could you clarify?

Comment: The point is that I don't think you *can* solve this. You'll need to use a different "through" model for each specific relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change "RoleTest" to "Role" and you need to have a foreign key to `BookingAgent`, not `Entity` (and shouldn't `Entity` be an abstract base class?)

```
class BookingAgent(Entity)
    staff = models.ManyToManyField(Individual, through='Role', related_name="employee")

class Role(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Individual)
    company = models.ForeignKey(BookingAgent)
```

Comment: Thanks! The "RoleTest" typo was only in my question here. I can't have the foregin key be to 'BookingAgent' because I also have 'ManagementCompany' etc. Or should I make a seperate 'Role' model for each one?

Comment: ouch. this is not so straightforward. You could make a seperate through table for each subclass of `Entity`. Alternatively you could merge all the subclasses of `Entity` and give it a `type` field that would be one of 'Booking Agent', 'Managment company' etc. Or you could use Django's content types to have a generic relationship from Role to whatever model. Probably none of these is ideal.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Some of my subclasses have different fields so instead of merging them into 'Entity' I'm going to take the Generic Relationship route. This tutorial helped: [link](http://blog.yawd.eu/2011/admin-site-widget-generic-relations-django/)